# Json.net - Parse array with unknown property name

Tags: c#, json.net

How can I select a property from a nested array when the name is not know at development time. For example if I wanted to get the name "SamsClub" from the "Store" array but did not want to hardcode the array name because there can be n number of arrays.

["sections"]["Store"]["name"]

Sample Json

```
{
"luna": [],
"sections": {
    "Bank": [
        {
            "name": "Costco"
        }
    ],
    "Store": [
        {
            "name": "SamsClub"
        }
    ],
    "Business": [
        {
            "name": "BJs"
        }
    ]
}}
```

So far my code looks like this.

`JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
 var pc = o.GetValue("sections");`

After that the rest of the code does not work or I am not utilizing the correct process. JToken looked promising but I am clearly missing something.

---

Revision 1 - Updated the json to include a live output from the source.

```
    {
"image_prefixes": [],
"prod_and_cats": {
    "Accessories": [
        {
            "name": "Logo",
            "position": 8
        }
    ],
    "Keys": [
        {
            "name": "Independent",
            "position": 8
        }
    ],
    "Bags": [
        {
            "name": "Nylon",
            "position": 10
        }
    ],
    "Lock": [
        {
            "name": "Camp",
            "position": 6
        }
    ],
    "Sweat": [
        {
            "name": "Decline Hooded Sweatshirt",
            "position": 0
        }
    ],
    "Door": [
        {
            "name": "Zip ",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
},
"api_update": "2018-02",
"release": "12/28/2019",
"week": "17"}
```

Comment: I'm confused about what you are trying to do.  You have JSON which has n arrays of which you don't know the names in advance.  You do know that the arrays will contain objects each having a `name` property.  So what are you trying to find out?  You want the (first or all) name value(s) from the  objects inside any of the arrays?  You want the (first or all) object(s) containing a specific name?  Something else?  Do you also want the name(s) of the containing array(s)?

Comment: Brian just saw you comment today.
I am trying to get every "Name" property from the objects in the arrays. If I can also get the names of the containing arrays that would be awesome but not needed.

Comment: @BrianRogers I updated the Json, the are six instances of the name property I am trying to get the data from.

Comment: Not sure if the json is causing an issue but when I try to parse the data using 
     `JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsonString);`
    `IList<JToken> results = o.Children().ToList();`
"prod_and_cats" is always empty

Answer (score 0):

This would work. However, I suggest you restructure your JSON to be more generic so that you would not have to go through the trouble.

```
        var str = "{\"luna\":[],\"sections\":{\"Bank\":[{\"name\":\"Costco\"}],\"Store\":[{\"name\":\"SamsClub\"}],\"Business\":[{\"name\":\"BJs\"}]}}";
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(str);
        var sections = o.GetValue("sections").ToList();
        var elem = sections.Find(x => x.ToList()[0][0]["name"].ToString() == "SamsClub");
```

Comment: Thanks Rawitas unfortunately I am only a consumer of the data and cannot change the structure,

Comment: But my code should be working without changing the structure right?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do recursive deserialization in `Dictionary<string,object>` :-) I'm usually do that in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the values of all `name` properties within the JSON, you can use [`SelectTokens`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) with a recursive descent [JsonPath expression](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to get them:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
List<string> names = o.SelectTokens("$..name")
    .Select(t => (string)t)
    .ToList();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qjeaMt

If you want the names with their corresponding array names, you can do it like this:

```
var namesAndCategories = o.SelectTokens("$..name")
    .Select(t => new
    {
        Name = (string)t,
        Category = ((JProperty)t.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent).Name
    })
    .ToList();

foreach (var item in namesAndCategories)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name + " (" + item.Category + ")");
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WmSOBU